# Custom entry on @Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The code below will only accept the colors contained in the model. How can it allow for the user to enter one that is not listed in the model ?

```
      <div class="form-group input-group-sm">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CarColor, new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CarColor, ViewBag.CarColorList as SelectList })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You cant (a `select` element only allows you to select from a list of options). You could look at using a autocomplete control such as [jQueryUI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) or a combobox plugin such as [Kendo](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox)

Comment: you can not unless you create a mechanism to add color like adding a textbox to add color if not present. You will need to do filtering to check if color exists or is a valid name or valid hex whatever.. You can then add color values to database ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that I would do it would to be to use [Select2](http://select2.github.io/select2/). Select2 is basically an awesome drop down list. The 'Loading Data' example shows you where to start.